# How do I pass parameter of inline new object?

Tags: vb.net

I have a method that accepts a string as a parameter.
The string I need to pass is the property of an instantiated object.
I don't need the object to stick around once I get the value of that property.

I know I can do this like so:

```
Dim x As New myClass1
foo.thing1 = MyMethod(x.Name)
x = New MyClass2
foo.thing2 = MyMethod(x.Name)
'etc...
```

But I would prefer to do this inline if possible, since I have to do this several times in a row with different MyClass types.

EDIT:

Figured it out:

```
foo.thing = MyMethod(new MyClass().Name)
```

Comment: You can't change the type of `x` like that.  Once you instantiate `x` as an instance of `myClass1`, you will get a compiler error if you try to later assign an object of type `MyClass2` to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foo.thing = MyMethod(new MyClass().Name)
```

Comment: I was somewhat surprised that this works (but it does). I would have gone with Olivier's version with the parentheses round `New MyClass`.

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
foo.thing1 = MyMethod((New myClass1).Name)
foo.thing2 = MyMethod((New MyClass2).Name)
```

You need the braces around `New myClass1`, otherwise VB thinks you are trying to create an object of type `myClass1.Name`, which, of course, does not exist.